# How to get teaching evaluations for a course as a TA / Co-instructor

Tags: faculty-application, course-evaluation

Some of the faculty-level academic jobs require teaching evaluations in the submission package, which gives rise to a need to acquire teaching evaluations.

My question is then, how can one obtain teaching evaluations for a course where one is either a co-instructor or a teaching assistant, but not the instructor? The setting is where there is no clear teaching evaluation mechanism for co-instructors / teaching assistants already in place.

Answer (score 5):

With the instructor's consent, create your own evaluation form and hand it out to students on the last day of class. Make it similar to the one they are filling out for the instructor. If possible, ask the same person who  anonymizes the other evaluations do so for you. At a minimum, leave the room and provide an envelope for them to be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably not very much you can do, other than ask for a letter of recommendation from the main instructor specifically about your performance as a TA/co-instructor. You should let the department -- whoever oversees the TA assignments and managements in your unit -- know that evaluations would be helpful. In my institutions, students evaluate each instructor separately, including the TA.